# Por que o "c_float()" está gerando valores incorretos?

Tags: python-3.x, float, ctypes

Estou criando um programa em Python — utilizando a biblioteca `ctypes` — para ler e escrever valores na memória, e quero ter precisão no tamanho do dado a ser lido e escrito.

No caso, se o valor de ponto flutuante tiver um tamanho de 4 bytes, o tipo dele deve ser `float`. Se ele tiver 8 bytes, ele deve ser um `double`. Para isso, estou utilizando o seguinte código:

```
def get_type(value, size):
    return ctypes.c_float(value) if size <= 4 else ctypes.c_double(value)
```

O problema é que o `ctypes.c_float`, diferentemente do `ctypes.c_double`, está sempre obtendo um valor `x.yz` e transformando em `x.ab`. Em outras palavras, ele gera um valor diferente depois do ponto. Veja os exemplos abaixo:

```
ctypes.c_float(590621.2148).value     # 590621.1875
ctypes.c_float(324456.234).value      # 324456.21875
ctypes.c_float(987.1).value           # 987.0999755859375
ctypes.c_float(456.234)               # 456.2340087890625
```

Eu sei que o `float` é menos preciso do que o tipo `double`, mas o problema está acontecendo desde o primeiro decimal! Algo curioso que eu notei é que quanto menor é o número à esquerda do ponto, menor é o erro nos números decimais. Vejam abaixo:

```
ctypes.c_float(590621.2148).value # 590621.1875       -> Todos os decimais errados
ctypes.c_float(90621.2148).value  # 90621.2109375     -> Os 2 primeiros decimais corretos
ctypes.c_float(621.2148).value    # 621.2147827148438 -> Os 3 primeiros decimais corretos
```

Por essa razão, cogitei a ideia de que o problema estivesse ocorrendo devido à falta de espaço do `float` para comportar o valor. Mas obviamente, é impossível que esse seja o motivo, já que esse tipo pode comportar números até 10 elevado a 38 — até onde eu me lembro.

A minha dúvida é: qual o motivo desse problema estar acontecendo e o que eu devo fazer para corrigir? Lembrando novamente que eu não quero utilizar o `c_double` para qualquer valor de ponto flutuante que aparecer, só para "corrigir" o problema. Eu quero colocar cada valor no seu tipo correto, por estética e para não ocupar espaço desnecessário.

Comment: Dá uma olhada [nessa tabela](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types). `ctypes.c_float` e `ctypes.c_double` alocam a mesma quantidade de memória. E aqui [`ctypes.c_float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_float) e [`ctypes.c_double`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.c_double) implementam internamente  tipos *C* [float e double](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types) que respectivamente usam 4bytes e 8bytes.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Olhei a tabela. Onde você viu que ambos alocam a mesma quantidade de memória? Só diz que ambos podem ser utilizados para `float` em Python (já que em Python, o unico tipo com ponto flutuante é o `float`). Se você utilizar a função `sizeof`, verá que eles tem tamanhos diferentes (4 bytes e 8 bytes). Quanto a segunda parte, sim eu sei disso, e foi o que eu acabei de falar... O que tudo isso tem haver com a pergunta afinal?

Comment: Veja https://ideone.com/EPhw5x, o que tem haver com a pergunta você está utilizando um tipo de precisão inferior com o mesmo consumo de memória.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Sim, esse é o tamanho do valor dele cru em Python. Mas e quanto ao tamanho do buffer criado para ele com o CTYPE? Veja aqui: https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#ctypes.sizeof

Comment: Então desses 24 bytes para `ctypes.c_float` 4 são alocados para float em , 4 ficam vazios e no outro são alocados 8 bytes do double. Não há vantagem computacional alguma.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Tenho a impressão de que você está se confundindo em alguma coisa. Esses 24 bytes não são do `C_FLOAT`, eles são do valor `float` do próprio Python. O atributo `value` retorna um valor `float`. Além disso, eu preciso passar o valor para um CTYPE para eu utilizar as funções do `winapi`.

Comment: Quem está se confundindo é você "esse buffer" fica dentro dos 24 bytes do tipo float.

Comment: @AugustoVasques Percebi agora o que você quis dizer (embora eu não faça ideia de como um tipo primitivo do Python tenha sido modificado dessa forma). Ainda assim, eu gostaria de saber o problema do `c_float`, e de bônus, o porquê do tamanho ser o mesmo na prática, embora a documentação diga o contrário.

Comment: Essa representação ctype é util quando quer serializar/desserializar dados em binário ou exportar dado ou ponteiro do dado para um lib. Para escrever direto na memória seria melhor usar o [módulo structs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)